# Bash reads files multiple times & output isn't right

Tags: bash, file, variables, for-loop, echo

I'm having a problem with reading multiple files and gathering info out of those files. Those files have an input like:

File1:

```
number1
text
number2
text
number3
text
```

File2:

```
number4
text
number5 
...
```

I only want to get the numbers out of every file, and those numers need to be placed under each other, but only 1 time.

Like this:

```
number1
number2
number3
number4
number5
```

What I have:

```
var0=$(echo "test")
var2=$(echo "test2")

for file in*.txt
do
     var1=$(awk -F .. do something "$file")
done
echo "$var0" "$var1" "$var2" >> myfile
```

So what i want it to do:

```
test1
here print var1 (so the numbers)
test2
```

The input files have something that i want to get out with the awk command, this works perfectly, when i echo the var i get number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number1,... so it keeps repeating the command.

When i print all the var's he only gives the value of the last file in var1:

```
test
number4
number5
test2
```

And I want everything, so also number1, number2,...

Ty in advance!

Comment: I don't understand all your codeflow, but you've clearly put `echo ... >> myfile` after the for loop.

Comment: Its very simple I get with the awk command some numbers, and that out of different files. And I want to print the output of all those files 1 time, always on a next line (happens with the awk commandà, and before the numbers I want some text similar to test. But the echo only gives the output of the last text file and not of all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your variable `$var1` inside the loop, so it's no surprise that you only get the contents of the last file.

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "test"}/^[0-9]+$/;END{print "test2"}' *.txt
```

This reads all of the `.txt` files in one awk command and prints any lines that only contain numbers (I'm assuming that's what you mean when you write *number1*, *number2* etc.)

However if you would like to continue using your approach, I guess the only thing you need to do is concatenate the output of each awk, rather than overwrite `$var1`:

```
var1+=$(awk -F .. do something "$file")
----^
```

If you don't actually care about the variable `$var1` there's no need to use concatenation, as shown by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in the comments:

```
{ echo "test"; for f in *.txt; do awk ... "$f"; done; echo "test2"; } >myfile
```

You can probably skip the loop too (which will be shorter and quicker):

```
{ echo "test"; awk ... "$f" *.txt; echo "test2"; } >myfile
```

...and if you can do that, we've arrived pretty much back at my first suggestion, which is to do the whole thing in one go using awk :)